# Why can't this site be viewed properly by Firefox?

Tags: firefox, website, internet-explorer-8

The following web page cannot be viewed properly by Firefox:

http://personel.saglik.gov.tr/

When I try to view it on Firefox (3.5.5), the source code of the page shows up. OTOH, it can be viewed by IE8. What could be the reason?

Comment: same problem for Chrome and Opera. IE6 and 7 are also fine.

Comment: I sent an email to them to correct the error. It is strange that a governmental site has those kind of errors...

Comment: All depends on who is doing the editing and what they are using to edit the document. This is normally the case if MS-Word was used to create /edit the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the reason:

```
<HTML xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

Try changing the doctype and schema to a [W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) and you should get a viewable page.

Comment: Thanks ricbax. I sent an email to them about this issue.